# facebook: how to display comments widget on a photo

Tags: facebook

i want to show comments and allow users to add new comments on a facebook photo

for example 
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150166311303306&set=a.10150166305773306.305513.40796308305&type=1

can i add ? i tried but couldn't get this to work

```
<fb:comments href="facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150166311303306"></fb:comments>
```

but i can't see the existing comments.

how can i fix this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, fb:comments is for external urls and specific content not in Facebook, i.e, a post, photo, or any other content on **your** site. On the other hand you could use the graph api to achieve your goal.

https://graph.facebook.com/10150166311303306/comments will retrieve all the comments for the photo in question. You should also be able to POST to that url to add a comment. You will need to add an access_token for either of these cases.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: hello 
thanks for you answer, i tried this but there is a problem for example lets try to take this request https://graph.facebook.com/10150166492579574/comments we will notice that the first comment has (1 likes) if i tried to get the person who liked this using this request https://graph.facebook.com/10150166492579574_5149390/likes i will get an empty array, i'm not sure if this is a known bug in facebook api but couldn't find a solution for that